# ASP.net chart control - XValueMembers Count

Tags: asp.net, .net, mschart, aspchart

This is the first time I use chart control in ASP.net

I did the binding between the chart and a datatable to show the stats of revenue per date

[image]

Although,
When the selected dates are more than 9, the chart stops displaying them all on the X axis

It displays only 5

[image]

**What is the reason?
Any workaround?**

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar problem was [found here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/73a3a5f8-7847-409d-8248-889444e0295b/problem-with-xvaluemember-in-the-chart-controls), and people there recommends to set up some properties, like this:

Try setting the `AxisX` Interval property to 1

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1
```

note that you may then also want to change the angle of the labels

And after that, as you'll get a lot of values at axis `X`, you should change the angle for them. like this:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 45
```

Note that `Chart1` is a Id of your chart, and can be different.

Comment: Thank you for the straightforward answer :)